# Почему возвращается пустой resultset? oracledb

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle12c

Выполняя один и тот же запрос в программе и в sql developer получаю разные результаты. в первом случае получаю пустой ResultSet, в метаданных есть хедер. во втором все нормально, данные есть. Не получается извлечь данные любой таблицs в бд кроме системных, все запросы отрабатывают без ошибок, но данные не приходят. Происходит все это только с одной базой данных, если подключится к другой все работает. Что может быть не так с этой бд?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь есть ли права на select, схему смотри туда ты обращаешься ли? Запусти в режиме дебага и посмотри по внимательнее, остальное только можно догадываться.

И случаем, не забыл ли ты commit сделать?

После добавления, удаления и изменения нужно делать commit чтобы данные записались в рамках транзакции.